# How to exit minibuffer with one key?

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer, quitting

How can I tell emacs that one key press of `<f12>` should terminate the minibuffer, like `C-g` does by default?

I tried in scratch buffer:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'keyboard-quit)
```

but if I go `M-x woopswrongcommand <f12>` i'm still stuck in the minibuffer.

(I tested this on emacs 27, started with -Q)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to bind keys for the minibuffer in a minibuffer keymap. If you want a key to work in *all* minibuffers then bind it in keymap `minibuffer-local-map`:

```lisp
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f12>") 'abort-recursive-edit)
```

And `C-g` in the minibuffer is bound to `abort-recursive-edit`, not `keyboard-quit`. So if you want to quit the minibuffer then bind your key to `abort-recursive-edit`.

You can easily see this binding of `C-g` and other minibuffer keys if you either have an Emacs 28 prerelease build or you use library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el). Those give you command **`describe-keymap`**, which `help-fns+.el` binds to **`C-h M-k`**.